# What has become of FunnelWeb?

Tags: literate-programming

I am a happy user of FunnelWeb, the Literate Programming tool advertised on http://ross.net/home/Cobwebs.html - apparently a minority, as that page says:

> Most programmers hate it, but the ones who love it really love it.

But today I saw that the link to http://www.ross.net/funnelweb/ given there is stale.

Does anyone know what has become of FunnelWeb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is only slightly broken. It works when you remove the "www": http://ross.net/funnelweb/